# What exactly is opening tables state in query execution?

Tags: mariadb

Many time i've seen queries stuck at "Opening Tables" state on mariadb. However, i couldn't find any documentation for the same.

1. When does this state occur?
2. If this state persists for a long time(say 30 seconds), is it bad? If it is, what could be causing it?

Comment: Which tool are you using to look at the state of the queries?

Comment: show processlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for mariadb, opening tables should be fast process and should not get stuck unless it's being blocked by a lock. For example an alter query can lock the table for open. You should also consider checking if your table_open_cache value is large enough.

Refer to mariadb manual on [thread states](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/general-thread-states/).